# How to trigger blur event of element manually in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I want to trigger blur event of element (id:ssp2) in Vue3, but no effect :

```
<el-input v-model.trim="parameter.ssp2"  type="password" id="ssp2"
```

```
const parameterRules = reactive({
      ssp: [{required: false, validator: function (rule, value, callback)  {
        ...
        callback();
document.getElementById('ssp2').blur();
this.$refs.formModal.validateField(['ssp2']);
      }, trigger: 'blur'}],
      ssp2: [{required: false, validator: ssp2Validate, trigger: 'blur'}]
    });
```

I tried following but no effect:

```
document.getElementById('ssp2').blur();
this.$refs.formModal.validateField(['ssp2']);
```